# Screen coordinates to percentage conversion

Tags: java, opengl

In Java, I am struggling to come up with a math formula to convert screen coordinates with a range of -1 to 1, to percentage coordinates of 0% to 100%.

So for example 50% would equal 0 in screen coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula is:

```
screen_coordinate * 50 + 50
```

If the output of this formula is 40, that means it is 40%.

Here is how you get the formula. The conversion is obviously linear, so it can be expressed as:

```
y = ax + b
```

Based on the given conditions, you can see:

```
0 = -a + b
100 = a + b
```

Solve the above, and get:

```
a = 50
b = 50
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not an android/java problem. That's a simple algorithm:

```
 float percent = (screen_coordinate+1)*50
```